# How to detect voice in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to fire some method on voice detection.

For Example,

Just like in `PragDuck` app, When user starts speaking `duck` starts its animation.

How can I detect users voice?

Comment: This is akin to asking how to "write an app in iOS".  What have you tried already?  You're going to get much better answers if you don't ask the community to solve the entirety of a rather complex problem for you.

Comment: Haven't you ever started anything that you didn't know how to guess the first step? no body is asking you to give him an app. just like @pinxue answer - give a little push in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AVAudioRecorder - Audio Metering - checkout out this tutorial - dettect when a user blows into mic http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

Quick Example:

`_audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;`

```
//1. This method will get the current mic activity and will format it to a 0 - 1 scale.

-(void)checkRecordingMeters:(NSTimer *)timer
{
      [_audioRecorder updateMeters];

      const double ALPHA = 0.2;
      float peakPower = [_audioRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0];

      double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * peakPower));
      lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

      NSLog(@"Meters: %f" , peakPower);
      NSLog(@"lowPassResults: %f \n" , lowPassResults);
}


//2. Call this method to run a loop timer to check the current mic activity
-(void)enableMettering:(BOOL)enable
{

    if(enable)
    {
        levelTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(checkRecordingMeters:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        [levelTimer invalidate];
        [levelTimer release];
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working ? Always printing that lowPassResults == 0.00000 but how can i detect when user blow on mic. Please tell me

Answer (score 1):

You may use AudioQueue to record and add a simple threshold filter to ignore environment noise. For lower latency, you may use AudioUnit.

Comment: Hey provide some links or samples in your answer.

Comment: @Devang: Hey, do some research of your own and don't expect others to work for you for free.

Comment: @JoshCaswell : I am tring on google but doesn't find any solution so asking for links.

Comment: @Devang: pixue just gave you a few useful pointers. You can go look at those items in the Apple docs, where there's sure to be sample code, and do further web searches based on the info.