# Automatically Start audio recording when user speaks

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to start recording when the user starts to talk and stops recording when the user is done talking. And I want to limit the maximum record audio length.I could not be able to find enough function in AVAudioRecorderDelegate.Hope you understand my problem.Thanks in Advance

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: Any) {
    recordingLabel.text = "Recording in progress..."
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

    try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}

@IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
    recordButton.isEnabled = true
    stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
    recordingLabel.text = "Tap to record..."

    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setActive(false)
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if (flag) {
        //Success
    } else {
        print("Could not save audio recording!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to start audio recording automatically without user press the UIButton

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484566/how-to-detect-voice-in-my-iphone-app

Answer (score -1):

To Record Audio When user tak1 you need some steps

**1. Permission from User to all your app to use Mic**

In your  *Info Plist* Add `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description`  in user Plist and add Text Description

**2. Location to save Recorded File**  user `FileManager`

**3. To End After time**  : use `audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 30)  // record for 30 Sec`

**Check complete code :**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

   @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: Any) {
        self.requestRecordPermission()
    }

    func requestRecordPermission() {
        recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
            try recordingSession.setActive(true)
            recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if allowed {
                        // User allow you to record

                        // Start recording and change UIbutton color
                        self.recordButton.backgroundColor = .red
                        self.startRecording()

                    } else {
                        // failed to record!
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // failed to record!
        }
    }
    func startRecording() {

        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recordedFile.m4a")

        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 30)  // record for 30 Sec
            recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Stop", for: .normal)
            recordButton.backgroundColor = .green

        } catch {
            finishRecording(success: false)
        }
    }
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }

    @objc func recordTapped() {
        if audioRecorder == nil {
            startRecording()
        } else {
            finishRecording(success: true)
        }
    }

    public func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil

        if success {
            // record sucess
            recordButton.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            // record fail

            recordButton.backgroundColor = .yellow

        }
    }

}


extension ViewController :AVAudioRecorderDelegate{


    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if !flag {
            finishRecording(success: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.but it's not working as expected.i am getting this error.
ca_debug_string: inPropertyData == NULL